# Dynamic sql query in SSRS (Sql Server Report Server 2012)

Tags: sql, dynamic, reporting-services

I have created in vs2010 a report with the name "`clients`", which shows a list of clients with the following attributes:

```
clientID,firstname,lastname,adres,country,birthday
```

I have created this report with a datasource and a dataset. In this dataset I have created a query like this:

```
select firstname, lastname, adres, country, birthday
from clients
```

This is working!

I would like to add 2 `optonal parameters`:

```
param_clientID ,param_birthDay
```

I would like to use these parameters in a where clausule ONLY if they are filled.

```
where clientID = param_clientID and birthday = param_birthDay
```

It should be possible that the clientID is filled, and the birthday parameter not. Otherwise also.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Adding (optional) parameters to you report is quite easy.

First of all make your parameters nullable.

```
select firstname, lastname, adres, country, birthday 
from clients
where (clientID = @clientID or @clientID is null) 
and (birthday = @birthDay or @birthDay is null)
```

For more detailed description:

- parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx
- optional parameters: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/egiardina/archive/2007/06/26/sql-server-reporting-services-optional-parameters.aspx

Comment: Original poster did ask to only include the where clause if the parameters are used. using or null can have serious performance issues